# MediaElement repeatedly play Exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, mediaelement

I'm new in WP7, and I am trying to play sounds with a `MediaElement` when I press a button.
Its works, but unfortunately I get "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" Exception when I press the button repeatedly, before the sound begins. How can I avoid that?

The Play method:

```
public void Play(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        mediaElement.Stop();
        mediaElement.ClearValue(MediaElement.SourceProperty);

        using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isf.OpenFile(@"shared\transfers\" + filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                mediaElement.SetSource(fileStream);
                mediaElement.IsMuted = false;
                mediaElement.Volume = 1.0;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Event handlers:

```
void me_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement.Play();
}

void me_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement.ClearValue(MediaElement.SourceProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like for the user to be allowed to click the play button only once. One way would be.

```
public bool IsPlaying = false;
    void me_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


    if(!IsPlaying){
        mediaElement.Play();
        IsPlaying = true;
        }
    }

    void me_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPlaying){
        mediaElement.ClearValue(MediaElement.SourceProperty);
        IsPlaying = false;
        }
}
```

Loading the `filestream` to a `memorystream`, before playing should make it more flexible, if you're dealing with low size streams.

Comment: The MediaElement doesn't allow to play a `MemoryStream`. I accept your solution, because I did it with a flag, as you mentioned. The difference is: I make true the flag, when the opening begins, and I make false, if the media opened.